# Querying instances contained in a list

Tags: list, class, instances, querying

I have created a list (dd) which contains instances of a class. I want to be able to perform queries on some of its attributes (eg. finding the smallest numeric value), but cannot find a way to do this using the functionality of the class (I feel like going back to analysing the data by column). How do I access the values in one of the attributes when my instances are now on a list? Thanks!

Comment: Specifying what language you are working with might be a useful starting point. Otherwise you might get suggestions from C++, Python, Java, or any other programming language that has the concept of a class and a list in it... Also, showing some code is generally considered useful.

Comment: Sorry... this was my first stackoverflow post... Im using python..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using C# and having a class like this

```
class Foo
{
    public double Bar { get; set; }
}
```

then LINQ is exactly what you are looking for

```
List<Foo> list = GetList();
var filtered = list.Where(p => p.Bar > 23.0);
```

Have a look at these examples:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b